# How to fix swift Index Out of Range ( 444 Index out of range) ..?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have a struct data, I am trying to populate the table view at the specified indices, but if try to use the `indexPath.row` attribute for data and cell labels, i am having `index out of range` error everytime..

my struct:

```
struct TradingPairs: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var baseAsset: String
    var quoteAsset: String
}

struct PairByTicker: Codable {
    var price: Float
    var ask: Float
    var askVolume: Float
    var bid: Float
    var bidVolume: Float
    var volume: Float
    var time: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case price = "price"
        case ask = "ask"
        case askVolume = "askVolume"
        case bid = "bid"
        case bidVolume = "bidVolume"
        case volume = "volume"
        case time = "time"
    }
}
```

and struct instance in ViewController:

```
 var tradingPair = [TradingPairs]()
 var pairByTicker = [PairByTicker]()
```

and in My TableView Cell `cell for row at` dequeue method:

```
 cell.name.text = self.tradingPair[indexPath.row].name
 cell.price.text = String(describing: self.pairByTicker[indexPath.row].price)
 cell.volume.text = String(describing: self.pairByTicker[indexPath.row].volume)
 return cell
```

--TableView DataSourse:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tradingPair.count + [self.pairByTicker].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TradingPairCell") as! TradingPairCell
//        for data in self.pairByTicker {
//            let pairs = data
//            cell.configure(data: pairs)
//        }
//        for data in self.tradingPair {
//            cell.configure(data: data)
//        }
        
        cell.name.text = self.tradingPair[indexPath.row].name
        cell.price.text = String(describing: self.pairByTicker[indexPath.row].price)
        cell.volume.text = String(describing: self.pairByTicker[indexPath.row].volume)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }
}
```

not sure why i am getting index out of range error.. (

Comment: post the code of tableview delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: Your `cellForRowAt` method accesses `self.tradingPair[indexPath.row]` but the `numberOfRowsInSection` method returns `self.tradingPair.count + [self.pairByTicker].count` – can you spot the problem?

Comment: @MartinR, kinda confused by your feedback, can you please elaborate a bit on this ?

Comment: Add this to your `cellForRowAt` method and you should see the problem: `print("Access element with index", indexPath.row, "number of elements in array is", self.tradingPair.count)`

Comment: You should have one data source for your table and not two (tradingPair & pairByTicket), try to combine them into one array.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, can you suggest your approach then, i mean how would you go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning cell for a section is `self.tradingPair.count + [self.pairByTicker].count` so if both array have 5 members then tableview aspects 10 rows data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

But in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it will work well for the index up to 4 and the app will get crash as soon as it try to get the object from that array for the index 5.

That is the reason of the crash and it will crash at line `self.tradingPair[indexPath.row].name` because the array tradingPair has only 5 member (from index 0 to 4) and it try to get the member of 5th index.

what you can do is you need to identify the exact number of rows for the tableview and then return the value for the method `numberOfRowsInSection` . like below...

Suppose you have the following model.

```
struct TradingPair {
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    var volume: Double
}
```

Initialise the array like below...

```
let tradingPair = [
    TradingPair(name: "name1", price: 12, volume: 15)
    TradingPair(name: "name2", price: 26, volume: 25),
    TradingPair(name: "name3", price: 37, volume: 12),
    TradingPair(name: "name4", price: 22, volume: 6)
]
```

The implementation of the delegate and datasource methods of table view...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tradingPair.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TradingPairCell") as! TradingPairCell

    let obj = tradingPair[indexPath.row]
    cell.name.text = obj.name
    cell.price.text = String(obj.price)
    cell.volume.text = String(obj.volume)

    return cell
}
```

Hope from the above example you get the idea how to implement it.